# Countdown script

Tags: javascript, datetime

I made a script in JavaScript to calculate how long it takes until a certain date.

Do you find it user-friendly enough? Is the code correct?

```
var object = "object"
function formatDate(date) { // get the date in proper format
var d = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();
    monthT = month;
    yearT = year;
    dayT = day;

if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

var time = new Object()
time.until = function(date, start){
  if (typeof start === 'undefined'){
  var currentTime = formatDate(new Date())
}else {currentTime == start}
  var year = date.substring(0, 4);
  var year = year - 1 + 1; // now it isn\'t a string anymore :D
  var month = date.substring(5, 7)
  var month = month - 1 + 1;
  var day = date.substring(8, 10);
  var day = day -1 + 1; // make it into a number in stead of string

  var curMonth = monthT
  var curDay = dayT
  var curYear =  yearT

    var curDay = curDay - 1 + 1;
      var curMonth = curMonth - 1 + 1;
      var curYear = curYear - 1 + 1;
    var monthBefor = month - 1;

      var difDay = day - curDay;
      var difMonth = month - curMonth;
      var difWeek = 0;
      if(difDay < 0) {
      difMonth--;
      if(monthBefor === 0){monthBefor = 12};
      switch(monthBefor) {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 8:
        case 7:
        case 10:
        case 12:
        difDay = difDay + 31;
        break;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 8:
        case 11:
        difDay = difDay + 30;
        break;
        case 2:
        if(year % 4 == 0) {difDay = difDay + 29}else{difDay = difDay + 28}
        break;
        default:
        console.log("error")
        break;

      }
      }
      if(difMonth < 0){
        difMonth += 12;
        year--;
        }
      while(difDay >= 7) {difDay = difDay - 7; difWeek++; }

      var difYear = year - curYear;
return {days: difDay, weeks: difWeek, months: difMonth, years: difYear};

},
time.today = function(object){
    var today = formatDate(new Date);
    if(object == "object"){
        var obj = {};
        var yearO = parseInt(today.substring(0,4))
        var monthO = parseInt(today.substring(5,7))
        var dayO = parseInt(today.substring(8,10))
        var obj = {_when: "today", year: yearO, month: monthO, day: dayO}
        return obj;
    }else{
    return today;
    }
};
time.tomorrow = function(object){
    var tomorrow = formatDate(new Date);
    if(object == "object"){
        var obj = {};
        var yearO = parseInt(tomorrow.substring(0,4))
        var monthO = parseInt(tomorrow.substring(5,7))
        var dayO = parseInt(tomorrow.substring(8,10)) + 1;
        var obj = {_when: "tomorrow", year: yearO, month: monthO, day: dayO}
        return obj;
    }else{

    var tomorrowBegin = tomorrow.substring(0,8)
    var tomorrowEnd = parseInt(dayT) + 1;
     tomorrow = tomorrowBegin + tomorrowEnd
    return tomorrow;
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
time.until("2015-09-08") // returns an object with
{days: 6,
months: 1,
weeks: 1,
years: 0}
```

---

```
time.today() // returns the current date in YYYY-MM-DD format
time.tomorrow() // returns the date of the next day in YYYY-MM-DD format
```

---

```
time.today(object) // returns the current date in an object, like
{_when: "today",
day: 26,
month: 7,
year: 2015}
time.tomorrow(object) // returns the date of the next day in an object, like
{_when: "tomorrow",
day: 27,
month: 7,
year: 2015}
```

Comment: It is working! I use it on http://wsms.ml

Comment: I've rolled back your edit - please see [this question on meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c/1765#1765) which explains what you can and can't do after receiving an answer.

Comment: @RobH oops sorry

Comment: It's not a problem :) just didn't want you to wonder why I had done it.

Answer (score 4):

Your indentation is really, really bad. I recommend copying and pasting this code into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and then hitting the `TidyUp` button at the top.

This will go through and add proper indentation to your code. Study from this proper indentation, so you know what to do in the future.

---

```
time.until = function (date, start) {
    if (typeof start === 'undefined') {
        var currentTime = formatDate(new Date())
    } else {
        currentTime == start
    }
```

Why are you bothering with `start` and `currentTime`? These parts are absolutely unnecessary and are just plain mean to the person who is trying to read your code and understand why you are using `==` to set `start` to `currentTime`.

Since you don't use `currentTime` or `start` anywhere else in that method, just get rid of them.

---

Avoid creating global variables:

```
monthT = month;
yearT = year;
dayT = day;
```

---

This line is just plain wrong:

```
var curDay = curDay - 1 + 1;
```

You are subtracting one from a variable, and then adding one to it? It seems to me that you are turning a string to a number here.

I did a little investigating and traced the variable `curDay` back to the local `day` of `formatDate`. *Why* are you turning `date` into a string?

```
day = '' + d.getDate()
```

The only place that you are using `dayT` in the code is when you are initially setting `curDay`. A few lines later, you are doing that weird `- 1 + 1` thing. If you just let `date` stay as it is and not add `''` to turn it into a string, you wouldn't have to do that weird trick.

---

Not all of the lines that need them have them: semicolons.

Add more to your code.

---

There is *a lot* more that needs to be said about your code. I may be able to edit my answer in the future, but I hope more people will add answers to this post.

Comment: indentation: fixed, `function (date, start)` was from something old..: removed, `var curDay = curDay - 1 + 1;`: replaced with `parseInt()`, added semicolons
But I need the global variables because I use them in another function

Comment: what else is wrong?